# Gallery in HTML,CSS, JavaScript is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, w3c

I hava small problem with gallery which I made(I'm beginner - still learning) according to this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img. When I click the first photo it works correctly, but rest of them doesn't seems to show up.

```js
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById("myImg");
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src = this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function() { 
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    background: #000;
}

#container{
    width: 960px;
    min-width: 600px;
    min-height: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid #adadad;
    background: #303030;
    z-index: 1;
}

.imgbucket{
    float: left;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
    border: 2px dashed #13b7bd;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgbucket:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    border: 2px dashed #00f6ff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #11f6ff;
}

/*Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3*/

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            
            
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
            
            <div class="imgbucket">
                <img id="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="original.jpeg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
            </div>
    
                    <!-- The Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                      <span class="close">&times;</span>
                      <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                      <div id="caption"></div>
                    </div>
    
</div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you link your images to an absolute URL so we can see them, or use placeholder images?

Comment: Please don’t fill out the question with dots. Consider writing more context around the issue, explaining what is wrong, what should be happening, and what attempts you have made to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` must be unique, in your case all images have the same `id`. Frist for each images replace attribute `id` by attribute `class`. Then replace `var img = document.getElementById("myImg");` by `var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");` and loop over each image.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".myImg");
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

imgs.forEach(img => {
  img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }

});


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #000;
}

#container {
  width: 960px;
  min-width: 600px;
  min-height: 800px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 1px solid #adadad;
  background: #303030;
  z-index: 1;
}

.imgbucket {
  float: left;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 15px;
  border: 2px dashed #13b7bd;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.imgbucket:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  border: 2px dashed #00f6ff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px #11f6ff;
}


/*Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3 Tu z W3*/

#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>

  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>

  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>


  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>

  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>

  <div class="imgbucket">
    <img class="myImg" alt="nazwa" src="https://picsum.photos/200" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
    <div id="caption"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you didn't fix it yet, as mentioned by Cedric

> id must be unique, in your case all images have the same id. Frist for each images replace attribute id by attribute class.

here you can find the diference between `id` and `class` that might help:

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/